# How to write the contents of a table to csv file using selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a web page with table that has more than 150 contents. But not all data is shown in a single page ie only 50 contents are shown in first page, like this the contents in the table are separated into five pages. So we first we have to get contents in the table from first page then move on to second page get the contents from table and so on.. for all four pages and write those contents in a csv file using selenium java.

So for I have tried this code , With this code I can get all data from table to csv file but my problem is when I open and check the csv file all the data's in table are appended in a single column. I need to get those data same as my table ie rows and column should be same as table

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Driver path");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.get("Page URL");
  WebDriverWait Wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
  WebElement table = Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("table-container-inner"))); //getting data from table in first page
  String dataoutput;
  dataoutput = table.getText();
  System.out.println(dataoutput);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@aria-label='Next']")).click(); // here i am moving on to next page by clicking next option
  WebElement table1 = Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("table-container-inner")));
  String dataoutput1 = table1.getText();
  System.out.println(dataoutput1);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@aria-label='Next']")).click();
  WebElement table2 = Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("table-container-inner")));
  String dataoutput2 = table2.getText();
  System.out.println(dataoutput2);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@aria-label='Next']")).click();
  WebElement table3 = Wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("table-container-inner")));
  String dataoutput3 = table3.getText();
  System.out.println(dataoutput3);

  String tableoutput = dataoutput + dataoutput1 + dataoutput2 + dataoutput3;

  String csvOutputFile = "table.csv";

  try (FileWriter writecsv = new FileWriter("C:\\Natesh\\Automation\\table.csv")) {
   writecsv.append(tableoutput);
  }
}
```

Comment: How about appending dataoutput one by one instead of appending tableoutput?

Comment: Hi Naresh,
when you do getText() of table , are you getting the whole Table content as a single string ? If so make sure to format the table content comma separated.
FileWriter.append() will simply write the string content to CSV, it won't format your data

For troubleshooting , please comment out Selenium code and just try writing to CSV file with hard coded data.So it would be easy to fix .Best of luck